# How to scan new aadhaar card QR code and convert it into xml or object?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, scanning

I am trying to convert the base10 encode data to base64 or xml or any readable format but no luck.

The data is like after scanning the qr code :
2374971804270526477833002468783965837992554564899874087591661303561346432389832047870524302186901344489362368642972767716416349990805756094923115719687656090691368051627957878187788907419297818953295185555346288172578594637886352753543271000481717080003254556962148594350559820352806251787713278744047402230989238559317351232114240089849934148895256488140236015024800731753594740948640957680138566468247224859669467819596919398964809164399637893729212452791889199675715949918925838319591794702333094022248132120531152523331442741730158840977243402215102904932650832502847295644794421419704633765033761284508863534321317394686768650111457751139630853448637215423705157211510636160227953566227527799608082928846103264491539001327407775670834868948113753614112563650255058316849200536533335903554984254814901522086937767458409075617572843449110393213525925388131214952874629655799772119820372255291052673056372346072235458198199995637720424196884145247220163810790179386390283738429482893152518286247124911446073389185062482901364671389605727763080854673156754021728522287806275420847159574631844674460263574901590412679291518508010087116598357407343835408554094619585212373168435612645646129147973594416508676872819776522537778717985070402222824965034768103900739105784663244748432502180989441389718131079445941981681118258324511923246198334046020123727749408128519721102477302359413240175102907322619462289965085963377744024233678337951462006962521823224880199210318367946130004264196899778609815012001799773327514133268825910089483612283510244566484854597156100473055413090101948456959122378865704840756793122956663218517626099291311352417342899623681483097817511136427210593032393600010728324905512596767095096153856032112835755780472808814199620390836980020899858288860556611564167406292139646289142056168261133256777093245980048335918156712295254776487472431445495668303900536289283098315798552328294391152828182614909451410115516297083658174657554955228963550255866282688308751041517464999930825273776417639569977754844191402927594739069037851707477839207593911886893016618794870530622356073909077832279869798641545167528509966656120623184120128052588408742941658045827255866966100249857968956536613250770326334844204927432961924987891433020671754710428050564671868464658436926086493709176888821257183419013229795869757265111599482263223604228286513011751601176504567030118257385997460972803240338899836840030438830725520798480181575861397469056536579877274090338750406459700907704031830137890544492015701251066934352867527112361743047684237105216779177819594030160887368311805926405114938744235859610328064947158936962470654636736991567663705830950312548447653861922078087824048793236971354828540758657075837209006713701763902429652486225300535997260665898927924843608750347193892239342462507130025307878412116604096773706728162016134101751551184021079984480254041743057914746472840768175369369852937574401874295943063507273467384747124843744395375119899278823903202010381949145094804675442110869084589592876721655764753871572233276245590041302887094585204427900634246823674277680009401177473636685542700515621164233992970974893989913447733956146698563285998205950467321954304

I have tried with old adhar qr scan which is giving xml format and I am parsing and getting data but in case of scanning new adhar qr code getting in above format, I also don't know which format it is. I need to decode this data and get in proper format like xml or object format.

This is my code :

```
    if (view == qr_check_box) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AbhaCard.this, ScanActivty.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, abhaQr);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == abhaQr && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra("barcode");
            if (barcode != null && barcode.displayValue != null) {
                try {
                    // Serializer(Simple library) is used for parsing xml data to object
                    Serializer serializer = new Persister();
                    String barcode_sting = barcode.displayValue; 
                    scanResult.setText(barcode_sting);
                    Log.e("QR_code", barcode_sting);
                     try (InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(barcode_sting.getBytes())) {
                   // this serializer is user for converting xml to object(PrintLetterBarcodeData) in          case of old  adhar card scanning , so i want for new adhar cared qr code , how to convert.
                        barcodeData = serializer.read(PrintLetterBarcodeData.class, stream);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }}**
```

// this is my PrintLetterBarcodeData class ised for parsing the xml to object

```
     @Root(name = "PrintLetterBarcodeData")
     public class PrintLetterBarcodeData {
     @Attribute(name = "uid")
     private String uid;
     @Attribute(name = "name")
     private String name;
     @Attribute(name = "gender")
     private String gender;
     @Attribute(name = "yob")
     private String yob;
     @Attribute(name = "co")
     private String co;
     @Attribute(name = "house")
     private String house;
     @Attribute(name = "street")
     private String street;
     @Attribute(name = "vtc")
     private String vtc;
     @Attribute(name = "po")
     private String po;
     @Attribute(name = "dist")
     private String dist;
     @Attribute(name = "subdist")
     private String subdist;
     @Attribute(name = "state")
     private String state;
     @Attribute(name = "pc")
     private String pc;
     @Attribute(name = "dob")
     private String dob;}
```

Comment: Have you read the specification document?  https://uidai.gov.in/images/resource/User_manulal_QR_Code_15032019.pdf

Comment: I have seen this and I have python code to decode also, so  if anyone is knowing python kindly convert this code snippet:

Answer (score 0):

This is python solution , If anyone knows python kindly convert in java send the code here.

```
      import zlib
      details = ["version","email_mobile_status","referenceid", "name", "dob", 
      "gender", 
       "careof", "district", "landmark",                         "house", 
       "location", 
       "pincode", "postoffice", "state", "street", "subdistrict", "vtc"]
       delimeter = [-1]
       data = {}
       def initializeData(base10encodedData):
        bytes_array = base10encodedData.to_bytes(5000, 'big').lstrip(b'\x00')
         decompressed_array = zlib.decompress(bytes_array, 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
        if not decompressed_array[0:2].decode("ISO-8859-1") == 'V2':
         details.pop(0)
         for i in range(len(decompressed_array)):
         if decompressed_array[i] == 255:
         delimeter.append(i)

         for i in range(len(details)):
         data[details[i]] = decompressed_array[delimeter[i] + 1:delimeter[i + 
         1]].decode("ISO-8859-1")
          data['adhaar_last_4_digit'] = data['referenceid'][0:4]
          data['adhaar_last_digit'] = data['referenceid'][3]
          data['mobile'] = False
          if int(data['email_mobile_status']) == 3 or 
          int(data['email_mobile_status']) == 2:
          data['mobile'] = True
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is for kotin

```
var details = arrayOf(
        "version", "email_mobile_status", "referenceid", "name", "dob",
        "gender",
        "careof", "district", "landmark", "house",
        "location",
        "pincode", "postoffice", "state", "street", "subdistrict", "vtc"
    )
    var delimeter = intArrayOf(-1)
    var data: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()

    open fun initializeData(base10encodedData: Int) {
        val bytes_array = ByteArray(5000)
        for (i in 0..4999) {
            bytes_array[i] = (base10encodedData shr 8 * (5000 - i - 1) and 0xFF).toByte()
        }
        var startIndex = 0
        while (startIndex < 5000 && bytes_array[startIndex].toInt() == 0) {
            startIndex++
        }
        val trimmed_array = ByteArray(5000 - startIndex)
        System.arraycopy(bytes_array, startIndex, trimmed_array, 0, 5000 - startIndex)
        val inflater = Inflater(true)
        inflater.setInput(trimmed_array)
        val decompressed_array = ByteArray(5000)
        try {
            inflater.inflate(decompressed_array)
        } catch (e: DataFormatException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        inflater.end()
        val decompressed_string = String(decompressed_array, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
        if (decompressed_string.substring(0, 2) != "V2") {
            details = Arrays.copyOfRange(details, 1, details.size)
        }
        var index = 0
        while (index < decompressed_string.length) {
            if (decompressed_string[index].code == 255) {
                delimeter = Arrays.copyOf(delimeter, delimeter.size + 1)
                delimeter[delimeter.size - 1] = index
            }
            index++
        }
        for (i in details.indices) {
            val start = delimeter[i] + 1
            val end = delimeter[i + 1]
            val value = decompressed_string.substring(start, end)
            data[details[i]] = value
        }
        data["adhaar_last_4_digit"] = data["referenceid"]!!.substring(0, 4)
        data["adhaar_last_digit"] = Character.toString(data["referenceid"]!![3])
        data["mobile"] = "false"
        if (data["email_mobile_status"]!!.toInt() == 3 ||
            data["email_mobile_status"]!!.toInt() == 2
        ) {
            data["mobile"] = "true"
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is in Kotlin